# Data is not getting stored in database for multiple check box in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, checkbox, laravel-5

I have created a form, in which I have a list of days to be selected multiple. But those days are not getting stored in database.

here is my controller:

```
public function store(EventRequest $request)
{
    $input = Request::all();
    $input['days_of_week'] = Input::get('days_of_week');
    Event::create($input);
    return redirect('event');
}
```

and my view is:

```
    @foreach($days as $day)
    <ul>
        <li>
            {!! Form::checkbox("days_of_week[]", $day, null) , $day !!}
        </li>
    </ul>
    @endforeach
```

when I return `Input::get('days_of_week');` it displays the check boxes I select.

How can I store checkbox value along with all the other fields present in form.

Comment: I am using laravel, That post is not useful for me

Comment: I want to  store that check box value, which user checks not the unchecked check-boxes value

Comment: Try checking `dd($input['days_of_week'])` what you've received within it, and work around it like as simple array

Comment: there is being displayed When i print `dd($input['days_of_week'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Jerodev said, you cannot store array to the database. What you can do is serialize the array and store it. Then when retrieving the value, you can unserialize it.

```
public function store(EventRequest $request)
{
    $input = Request::all();
    $input['days_of_week'] = serialize(Input::get('days_of_week'));
    Event::create($input);
    return redirect('event');
}
```

and you can retrive it like this

```
$daysOfWeek = unserialize(Event::find(1)->days_of_week);
```

Comment: What should be datatype of the field? I have taken Varchar.

Comment: Then that is also not working, no data is being stored

Comment: do you get any error messages? can you post them here

Comment: nope, no error! actually when i print `Input::get('days_of_week')` It shows selected check-box value.then why it is not getting stored in database?

Comment: Also make sure in your Event modal you have `protected $fillable = ['days_of_week'];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98557/discussion-between-milan-maharjan-and-shweta).

Comment: what is the size of varchar days_of_week field? make sure its long enough, 1000 would be fine for now. please try that

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add an array to the values for the database, you will have to split this in seperate fields. I don't know what your database looks like, but here is an example on how to do this.

```
foreach (Input::get('days_of_week') as $key => $value) {
    $input['day_of_week_' . $key] = $value;
}
```